# How to create test helper that logs in using token authentication (not session)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

I'm trying to create a test helper for logging in. I have:

```
def log_in_as(user, options = {})
  password = options[:password] || 'password'
  if integration_test?
    post sessions_path, session: { email: user.email, password: password }
  else
    # post to create method in sessions controller
    # post :create, controller: SessionsController, session: { email: user.email, password: password }
  end
end

private
  def integration_test?
    defined?(post_via_redirect)
  end
```

This works for integration tests. But I don't know what to post in the else part of the method for controller and model tests. How can I there post the same to the create method in the sessions controller?

The code I suggest above (commented line in the `else` part) results in the error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches`.

**Update:** To provide more information: the authentication system I'm using stores a decrypted token in a cookie. A method checks that the digest in the cookie matches the token stored in the db for the user. I'm not using `session` for authentication.

For every db requests it is checked whether token and digest match:

```
def authenticated?(attribute, token)
  digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
  return false if digest.nil?
  BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
end
```

The helper method should ensure that the `authenticated?` check passes, also for controller methods. So that I can do my tests, which require a user to be logged in (i.e. they should pass that test before they can for example get a page).

Comment: Are you using `devise` for authentication?

Comment: No I have my own authentication system.

Answer (score 0):

Following Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/), specifically section 8.4.6, listing 8.50, you could use the following as your `else` branch: `session[:user_id] = user.id`.  The assignment would then occur when any non-integration (e.g. controller) test is run.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using session authentication. Only token authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can add token in your request header.

```
request.headers['HTTP_AUTH_TOKEN'] = token
```

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate a bit further? What do you mean with request header? Should I add this line to the test helper?

Comment: Depends how you are using auth token for authentication. Are you storing token in the session? Do you compare that token with the token in the header?

Comment: I've added a bit more information to the post. I'm not using `session`. Instead, I'm storing a hashed version of the token in a cookie on the user's pc and store the token in the db. Authentication than checks whether the two match.